# The following program has issue in "else" part

Tags: java, arrays

I want the "else" part only if no subString matches in the entire combination or like finally only if no matching found.

code:

```
public class Stringg {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        char[] array1 ={'a','c','t','i','a','n','c','e'};
        String Str2 ="cti";

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length-Str2.length(); i++) 
        {
            String Str ="";
            for (int j = i; j < i+ Str2.length(); j++) 
            {

                Str+=array1[j];

            }

            if(Str.equalsIgnoreCase(Str2))
            {
                System.out.println("This is a substring");
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("This is not a substring");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

output:

```
This is not a substring

This is a substring
```

Comment: If you are expecting more results, you should remove the `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `boolean isSubstring = false` before the main for loop, then if there ever is a matching substring, set `isSubstring = true`. Then once the entire loop finishes just have an if statement such as:

`if(isSubtring == false) {
    System.out.println("This is not a substring");
}`

Answer (score 1):

Move the `System.out.println("This is not a substring)` after the for-loop and replace break with return. This way the method will exit if it is a substring. If it isn't it won't exit and this way only if the entire combination won't match it will print `This is not a substring`.

Final result will look something like this:

```
class Stringg {
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        char[] array1 = {'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'e'};
        String Str2 = "cti";

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            String Str = "";
            for (int j = i; j < i + Str2.length(); j++)
                Str += array1[j];

            if (Str.equalsIgnoreCase(Str2)) {
                System.out.println("This is a substring");
                return;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("This is not a substring");
    }

}
```

It works like this:

1. check if there is a match
2. if there is print `This is a substring` and exit the method, else repeat 1st step
3. if none of the combinations succeeded print `This is not a substring`

Comment: Thanks. It works.. i also found when Str2="nce".. i returns string not found.. but actually it matches. any idea why?

Comment: @SureshKumar it's because in the 1st loop you made: `i < array1.length - Str2.length()`. I have no idea why would you do it. It should be `i < array1.length`.

Comment: my idea was... if main string is "actiance" (length 8) and substring is "cti" (length 3)... i want to split main string as act,cti,tia,ian, anc, nce... since substring lenght is 3...im splitting as 3 digits... but i ndt want "ce" or "e" as they are 2 and 1 digits which anyway not gona match my substring... but this logic should also match when substring length changes to 2 or 4..etc

Comment: @SureshKumar Oh, ok. My solution will check if `Str2` contains any of the letters from `array1` array. If I answered your question, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way

```
    public class Stringg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int matchingCount = 0;

        char[] array1 = {'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'e'};
        String Str2 = "cti";

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length - Str2.length(); i++) {
            String Str = "";
            for (int j = i; j < i + Str2.length(); j++) {

                Str += array1[j];
            }

            if (Str.equalsIgnoreCase(Str2)) {
                matchingCount++;
                System.out.println("This is a substring");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchingCount < 1) {
            System.out.println("This is not a substring");
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
This is not a substring
```

Comment: Matching count will always be 0. It's better to use a boolean because from what I know it won't use as much memory. It's a small amount anyway so it doesn't matter much on small projects but on big it may have a bigger difference. Even though boolean approach is using less memory I think my is even better because it's not using any addititonal memory.